# Cross platform mobile HTML5 app with .NET / C# as the technology stack - pointers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, mobile

I'm trying to figure out various pieces that need to go into building for the mobile web with .NET / C#. I've so far been working mostly with native app development (iOS / Droid / B'Berry) and have very little experience with web development in general. But for the current project I'm working on, I believe a web-app is the way to go and would like to figure out what I pieces I need to get it working.

To give a brief overview of the application, our company uses SQL Server / .NET / VS for all of our web dev projects. The programmers here are familiar with this stack and I would like to keep it that way if possible. We're building a new product that needs a web + mobile view. The web view is currently being built as a separate project completely, but that can be changed if needed.

I'm just looking for some input on how to design something that handles screen resolutions, device types etc. and creates layouts appropriately in VS. Also, any best practices when trying to do this are much appreciated.

Thanks, 
Teja.

Answer (score 0):

> handles screen resolutions, device types etc. and creates layouts appropriately

This is all presentation layer and shouldn't be a concern for any development framework. Sadly, it is. For instance, I'm currently working with a JSF team and so much of the presentation layer is produced via the JSF framework and it's a nightmare to maintain a sane presentation layer code base that way.

.net used to be that way too. Much of the early days of asp.net was full of invalid markup, bloated generated JS and the legendary postback cache tag.

Ideally, you'd have a presentation layer team that was independent of the particular framework. Mobile apps, more than anywhere, require the ability to maintain a lean, streamlined presentation layer and the best way to handle that is to let your team write their own HTML, CSS and JS as needed. I've worked with a C# team that was heavily using RESTful services that worked fairly well. We had built our own template framework and all HTML, CSS and JS was completely independent of the back end C#.

Fortunately, MS has gotten better and newer ways to implement via asp.net (such as the MVC model) can hopefully offer you better management of the presentation layer.

Comment: Interesting, so should I let people continue developing aspx pages for the web product and use some framework like Sencha to ping the web service for data when developing for mobile? Is that how this is usually done?

Comment: I'm not sure there is one 'usual' answer to this. I'd investigate any .net framework that already integrates a solid front end library...Sencha or jQuery Mobile. That'd get you halfway there.

Comment: My head is slightly messed up at this point. Where would I implement all the good stuff like business logic etc. if you were using one of these mobile frameworks? Just use javascript to do it?